# SMSManager Android report delivery (multiple sending SMS)

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I have this specific code, that runs on emulator. (I haven't tested to the real device yet). The purpose is to send a same text message to all numbers.
With the BroadcastReceiver that I have made some customization inside of it.

I wonder, how to get the report of each successfully (delivered) SMS?
Please consider which one of my options are correct:

1. Do I need to assign each call of PendingIntent with its
   registerReceiver?
2. or is it enough to set it just once? (please check the code below).

Because What I'm afraid is that, all of the messages are sent. But no delivery status I could be obtained (due to the mistakes of the broadcastreceiver assignment).

```
private void sendingSMS(){
        // this method will be repeatedly called because the phoneNumbers are stored inside the ArrayList

        PendingIntent sentPI = null, deliveryPI = null;

        if(smsMan == null){
            smsMan = SmsManager.getDefault();

            Intent sentIntent = new Intent("SENT_SMS_ACTION");
            sentIntent.putExtra("PhoneNum", phoneNumbersSelected.get(startIndexPhoneNumbers));

            Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent("DELIVERED_SMS_ACTION");
            deliveryIntent.putExtra("PhoneNum", phoneNumbersSelected.get(startIndexPhoneNumbers));

            sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, sentIntent, 0);
            deliveryPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, deliveryIntent, 0);

            registerReceiver(new MyBReceiver(MyBReceiver.SENT), new IntentFilter("SENT_SMS_ACTION"));
            registerReceiver(new MyBReceiver(MyBReceiver.DELIVERY), new IntentFilter("DELIVERED_SMS_ACTION"));

        } 

        smsMan.sendTextMessage(phoneNumbersSelected.get(startIndexPhoneNumbers), null, composedMessage, sentPI, deliveryPI);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Trying to send SMS to " + phoneNumbersSelected.get(startIndexPhoneNumbers), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

And the BroadCastReceiver is here

```
package project.fgroupindonesia.smsmassal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyBReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public MyBReceiver(){
        // default
        setUsage(SENT);
    }

    public MyBReceiver(int mode){
        setUsage(mode);
    }

    public static int SENT = 0, DELIVERY = 1;
    int usage;

    public void setUsage(int val){
        usage = val;
    }

    private int getUsage(){
        return usage;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        if(this.getUsage() == SENT){

            switch(getResultCode()){
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(arg0, "SMS is sent to " + arg1.getStringExtra("PhoneNum"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(arg0, "ERROR GENERIC while sending to " + arg1.getStringExtra("PhoneNum"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(arg0, "RADIO OFF while sending to " + arg1.getStringExtra("PhoneNum"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(arg0, "ERROR NULL while sending to " + arg1.getStringExtra("PhoneNum"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

        } else if(this.getUsage() == DELIVERY){

            // some code
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "SMS is delivered to " + arg1.getStringExtra("PhoneNum"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you found an answer, i have the same problem